# C declaration from standard signal Library

Tags: c, function

So can someone explain what this is supposed to do:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)) ) (int);
```

It is a definition taken from the standard signal library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start with the name:

```
signal
```

Go right as far as you can:

```
signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))
```

You have a parenthesized list of parameters, so it's a function taking 2 parameters: an `int` named `sig` and a function pointer named `func` (you can analyze it in the same way later).

Then you hit another rightparen, so you go left:

```
*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))
```

So the function `signal` returns a pointer to... something. Let's take down the parenthesis and go right again, since we can:

```
(*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)) ) (int)
```

We have again a parenthesized list of arguments, so `signal` returns a pointer to function which takes an `int` as an only argument. Then go left again:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)) ) (int)
```

Thus the function `signal` returns the pointer to function taking `int` and returning `void`.

Yes, this language is weird, but at least it's consistent. :)

Answer (score 7):

The function `signal` takes as arguments:

```
int sig - a signal value
void (*func)(int) - a pointer to a function that takes an int and returns void
```

and returns:

```
void (*)(int) - a function that takes an int and returns void
```

`signal` registers a function to be called when the signal occurs and returns the previous function handler.

Answer (score 1):

Basically it allows to decide how to handle a specific signal (identified by argument `int sig`) sent to your program.

The `void (*func)(int)` is a pointer to the function that will handle the signal (you can provide a custom one or use `SIG_DFL` `SIG_IGN` which are default actions to manage it normally or ignore it).

The function `signal` then returns the pointer to the handler present BEFORE the call of this function or `SIG_ERR` is an error occurred. This can be used to restore the default handler lately when you've done with custom behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The man page makes this declaration easier to understand by introducing a `typedef` as:

```
typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);

sighandler_t signal(int signum, sighandler_t handler);
```

`sighandler_t` is defined as a pointer to a function that accepts an `int` and returns `void`.

`signal` is a function that accepts an `int` (signal number) and a function pointer and returns a function pointer.